# dispaly image from remote server on the page ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I want to display the photo through the Path which is saved on the database Like this `\\94.19.247.273\C$\\t\q\laptop.com\bb\images\UrunImages\a1\14-09-18-_04-17-00.jpg` .
I have `mothod` to convert the path

```
 public FileContentResult ImagePath(string path)
    {

        string str1 = "C:/";
        string str2 = "//94.19.247.273/C$//";
        string result = path.Replace(str2, str1);

        byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(result);
        return new FileContentResult(imageArray, "image/png");
    }
```

I get it from Stackoverflow and on the `View` like this

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.ProductPhotoPathList)
                {
                    <li data-thumb="@Url.Action("ImagePath","Home",new { path = item})">
                        <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Url.Action("ImagePath","Home",new { path = item})" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </div>
                    </li>
                }
```

but here is a problem when page load `ImagePath` method work successfully but on the page i still get the Path like which is saved on the database `\\94.19.247.273\C$\\t\q\laptop.com\bb\images\UrunImages\a1\14-09-18-_04-17-00.jpg`, so i can not get changed path on the page.I want to get path like this :`C:\t\q\laptop.com\bb\images\UrunImages\a1\14-09-18-_04-17-00.jpg` 
what the problem might be?

i have this path
`/Home/ImagePath?path=%2F%2F94.19.247.273%2FC%24%2F%2FBaburtechAnakartImage%2FACER_murtaza%20test1%2F1_ACER_murtaza%20test1_12-09-18-_11-20-02.jpg`.

so i want to convert it to `/Home/ImagePath?path=C%3A%2FBaburtechAnakartImage%2FACER_murtaza%20test1%2F1_ACER_murtaza%20test1_12-09-18-_11-20-02.jpg`.

the method convert it correctly but i can not get it on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add this on the top of your razor

```
@{
    var split = "httpdocs/";
}
```

2) Then change your `li` like

```
<li data-thumb="@Url.Content("~/" + item.Substring(item.IndexOf(split) + split.Length))">
    <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Url.Content("~/" + item.Substring(item.IndexOf(split) + split.Length)) " data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Str1 and str2 use forward slashes (/), your path has backslashes (\)

Comment: yes you are right,path is saved with backslashes (\) on the database but when sent to method its convert to slashes (/), method works right.